# ASP.NET Core 6 API generates a lot of sessions in Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, rest, asp.net-core

I'm working with ASP.NET Core 6, using it as a backend, and I've encountered the issue of it creating many sessions in the database over time. Sometimes there are 14 sessions, sometimes 300. I've been monitoring this for a while and noticed that around 90% of these sessions are not being used. Consequently, I limited the user that the database uses to a maximum of 15 sessions. Surprisingly, everything still works flawlessly.

My question here is, when are sessions started? One should ideally suffice. I have my DBContext injected everywhere, I neither generate new instances nor use any other features except for querying tables.

I checked my code for any mistakes but found nothing, and I revisited the Microsoft documentation, but unfortunately, I couldn't find anything on how they handle sessions with the database.

Comment: Taking a blind guess - it is ADO.NET maintaining connection pool (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76764224/2501279) for a bit more info). You can try manipulating the pool size via connections string (see [this](https://www.connectionstrings.com/net-framework-data-provider-for-oracle/using-connection-pooling/) and [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/win.101/b10117/features001.htm)), try adding `Max Pool Size = 15;` to your connection string.

Comment: Thank you, that's very insightful. I didn't find anything on the topic at all, but my issue is temporarily resolved with the Max Pool Size. I'll now delve further into the topic.

Comment: @StephanStieger what issue? Are you sure there was anything wrong (there wasn't) and that your change didn't *cause* an issue? Which it did, a serious one. Opening a connection takes time which is why all database drivers and stacks use connection pooling to maintain a pool of reusable connections. By limiting connections you prevent the web app from handling lots of concurrent requests, by forcing it to wait for connections to be released. `One should ideally suffice` that's completely wrong, even for a desktop applications, because it would *prevent* data access from multiple threads.

Comment: Instead of throttling the web app you should find the *code* that doesn't close connections when it should. Keeping one connection open for long means that *other* requests have to open new connections. The normal way to use connections, shown in all docs and tutorials, creates connections in a `using` block and closes them as soon as possible. This way, they're available for reuse. `One should ideally suffice` means that 300 concurrent requests require 300 connections. On the other hand, a `using` block means 300 requests may only need 10 connections

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you are wrong. See Guru Stron's comment: ADO.NET uses connection pooling, when a `DbConnection` is disposed the DB session is not closed. Within a web app you want enough open connections to handle requests bursts.

Comment: @Richard you misunderstood what I wrote. In fact, the last statement can be called dead wrong, but I suspect you don't mean that connections kept open by requests or singletons, so they can't be used by new requests, somehow help with bursts.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos no I didn't: there is no evidence that code is keeping things open (that artificially limiting the sessions didn't have major effects indicates this). However comments are not a medium to go through details reasoning.

Comment: @Richard and yet you jumped to the conclusion that I don't understand what connection pooling is, or that I claimed disposing actually closes the connection. I've been using connection pooling since the ADO and COM days to reduce the number of connections needed for high traffic systems. I suspect you've been doing the same as well

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos indeed I did: because your comment read very much like discussions where a party (often a DBA) didn't understand the implications of connection pooling. Sorry for any offence.

Comment: DBAs know a lot more about connections and performance issues than the vast majority of programmers. Just like the hen, pig and bacon joke, programmers are involved but DBAs are committed

Answer (score 1):

> my issue is temporarily resolved with the Max Pool Size.

EF Core works on top of database drivers which usually maintain connection pool for perfromance reasons. If you have burst type of load in your application (i.e. sometimes you have a lot of parallel requests to the database) connection pool and number of created connections can grow and be maintained for some time (due to the pooling).

A bit strange though that the default size of pool is exceeded in some cases (it is 100 according to the docs). In theory this can be affected by opened transactions (at least AFAIK for other database engines/drivers).

Moving from comment by [Panagiotis Kanavos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos):

> The high number of connections is almost certainly due to misuse (eg using explicit transactions during a request) or an attempt to keep one connection open for long, perhaps an entire request. EF doesn't open a connection unless it has to load or save

See also:

- [Managing PostgreSQL connection for the best performance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76764136/2501279)
- [Using Connection Pooling using Microsofts OracleConnection](https://www.connectionstrings.com/net-framework-data-provider-for-oracle/using-connection-pooling/)
- [Oracle® Data Provider for .NET Developer's Guide
  10g Release 1 (10.1)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/win.101/b10117/features001.htm)
- [Why Maximum Pool Size limits the total number of connections?](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/5269) (for Npgsql @ github)

Comment: The high number of connections is almost certainly due to misuse (eg using explicit transactions during a request) or an attempt to keep one connection open for long, perhaps an entire request. EF doesn't open a connection unless it has to load or save.